# MYSQL - Select only rows with status not changed

Tags: php, mysql, database

please i need help in this Topic :

i have a table with multiple rows having multiple status like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5P4V.png)

but i want to get only rows where the status equal status="NA"
for all lead_id : like this :
 [the same lead_id / phone_number / status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ath61.png)

The same lead_id / and phone_number but status usualy equals to "NA"

Comment: try with a simpe sql tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You just need a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT lead_id, status, phonenumber
FROM t
WHERE status = 'NA'
```

Replace t with the name of your table.

Comment: its not what i want !! because i get a list of rows with same lead_id but many status (NA, REP, ABSENT) .. look the first picture !!

Comment: The query above returns all the rows you highlighted in red. If you want only unique values, replace "SELECT" with "SELECT DISTINCT"

Answer (score 0):

that it 
thnx for all reply

SELECT lead_id as id,COUNT(`lead_id`) AS TOTAL FROM vicidial_log GROUP BY lead_id HAVING TOTAL =(SELECT COUNT(lead_id) FROM vicidial_log WHERE `status`='NA' AND lead_id=id)